# Arabic text not displaying properly

Tags: php, dompdf, ar-php

I have Arabic text(html file) coming dynamically inside pdf using DomPdf and ar-php library.

I am just showing a line below in the $html variable but the text are not properly displaying, means they are not sorted altogether.

```
require_once 'ar-php/src/Arabic.php';
$Arabic = new ArPHP\I18N\Arabic();

$html = يقول الله عز وجل :(وكلوا واشربوا ولا تسرفوا إنه لا يحب المسرفين) الأعراف

$p = $Arabic->arIdentify($html);

for ($i = count($p)-1; $i >= 0; $i-=2) {
    $utf8ar = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs(substr($html, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]));
    $html   = substr_replace($html, $utf8ar, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]);
}
```

but its coming like `لا يحب المسرفين) الأعراف يقول الله عز وجل :(وكلوا واشربوا ولا تسرفوا إنه`

Pls any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dompdf does not fully support Arabic. You would need to pre-process your text through another program such as ArPHP before rendering to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

$html = "يقول الله عز وجل :(وكلوا واشربوا ولا تسرفوا إنه لا يحب المسرفين) الأعراف";

You forgot quotas and semicolon

Comment: I have already added quotes and semicolon.